# Does x86 instruction SHL/SHR actually rotate the bits?

Tags: assembly, x86

I was debugging a program. When the register di=0x01, cl=0x11,
The instruction "shl  di,cl" will actually make di=0x1.

Shouldn't the bits that slide off the end disappear?

Comment: how are your debugging it?

Comment: They do not rotate. For rotation you have `rol` and `ror`. The instruction `shr` does however keep the sign bit if it's set.

Comment: [CLI is an instruction ("Clear Interrupt"), not a register](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_31.html). What is "cli=0x11" supposed to mean?

Comment: I also think your observation is incorrect.  I don't know of any circumstances in which "shl di,cl" causes di to be unchanged when cl has any of the low 4 bits set.

Answer (score 2):

(Disregarding the example in the question as it clearly has typos.)

The higher bits of the shift amount are ignored, unless you're running your program on an original 8086: [See "IA-32 Architecture Compatibility" at the bottom of the page.](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html)

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am the author of the following article.

[Accessing and Modifying Upper Bits in x86 and x64 Registers](http://dsasmblr.com/accessing-and-modifying-upper-half-of-registers/)

The aim of the article is to provide the reader with a detailed, example- and code-laden explanation of exactly how the shift and rotate instructions work in both x86 and x64 contexts. The examples therein are directly applicable to OP's inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

SHL and SHR work using the following syntax dest, count

now di is a 16 bit register and CL is basically the count (3)

so you are right it should be zeroed out and you can prove this by using a online x86 emulator

http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/asm86/

and enter the following asm instructions:
mov di, 01h
mov cl, 11h
shl di, cl

so i dont know what would make it behave this way.